# .sbr files in Source Control

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, .sbr

I just started working on my first Visual Studio project, and I imported all the existing code for the project into an SVN repo of mine without checking which files were binary and which weren't.  So now I'm trying to clean up the repo and I've come across some .sbr, .pch, and .res files.

I figure the .pch file doesn't need to be in source control because it's binary. But the sbr and res files are currently empty, so I can't tell offhand if they should be in the repo.  So should they be in or out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.res` files are compiled versions of `.rc` files, so they don't need to be in the repository either.

After removing all the files you don't believe are necessary (most non-text files except images are probably not necessary), you should check out your project into a clean directory and attempt to do a full build. If it fails, then you removed too much. (If it succeeds, then you may be able to remove more stuff!)

Answer (score 3):

They should not be in the repo. They are all intermediate files created during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Res may be necessary since they can contain resources. SBR is source browser and should be created on compile if you're using the /Fr option (I think).

Edit: Never mind, I assume the poster above me is correct. Make sure you have the .rc/rc2 files then.

Answer (score 0):

.pch files are pre-complied headers and do not need to be included in SVN. They will be recreated when you check out your codebase and and do a build.